# Capistrano 2 Delayed_Job Tasks Fail To Use RBEnv Configured Ruby

Tags: ruby, capistrano, rbenv

Using [Capistrano 2.15](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), *config/deploy/production.rb* has:

```rb
set :bundle_flags, "--deployment --quiet --binstubs"
set :default_environment, {
   'RAILS_ENV' => 'production',
   'RBENV_ROOT' => "$HOME/.rbenv",
   'PATH' => "$RBENV_ROOT/shims:$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
}
```

In *config/deploy.rb* a task to test the ruby environment and version:

```rb
# Test Ruby Environment
desc "Test Ruby Environment"
task :test_ruby_environment, :roles => :app do
  run "env; ruby -v"
end
```

The output of `cap test_ruby_environment` omits the $RBENV_ROOT directory in the PATH:

```rb
** [out :: ex.org] RBENV_ROOT=/home/app/.rbenv
** [out :: ex.org] PATH=/shims:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

The [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) (3.0.5) daemon was running the system ruby when I needed the ruby
configured by rbenv.  The evidence for this was in an error trace from delayed_job:

```rb
/home/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:95:in `invoke_job'
```

which shows the system installed 1.8 gem source.

**Why does this not pick-up the rbenv configured ruby?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, because *:default_environment* is a hash, Capistrano does not necessarily produce the environment settings in order.

With the PATH setting generated before RBENV_ROOT, the environment variable used in the PATH is empty.

The solution was not to rely on RBENV_ROOT in the PATH:

```rb
set :bundle_flags, "--deployment --quiet --binstubs"
set :rbenv_root, '$HOME/.rbenv'
# be careful, these might not play back in order written
set :default_environment, {
    'RAILS_ENV' => 'production',
    'RBENV_ROOT' => fetch(:rbenv_root),
    'PATH' => "#{fetch(:rbenv_root)}/shims:#{fetch(:rbenv_root)}/bin:$PATH"
}
```

Now the output has:

```rb
 ** [out :: ex.org] RBENV_ROOT=/home/app/.rbenv
 ** [out :: ex.org] PATH=/home/app/.rbenv/shims:/home/app/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

And the delayed_job tasks run with the ruby configured by rbenv.